# How to keep table values after changing database version?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using `greendao` library for database operations. I have some doubts,

1. Currently when i add any `entity` in one of the `database table`, i
   have to update my **databse version** to the next one. If i don't update
   the version app,crashes for some reason.Does it really need to update database version every time i add or update the table entities?
2. However,when i update the **database version**, all database values gets cleared.How to keep database values unchanged after updating database version?

Please help with this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to write migrations to prevent wiping your data.

Here is sample code how it is look:

```
public class DatabaseUpgradeHelper extends DaoMaster.OpenHelper {
    public DatabaseUpgradeHelper(Context context, String name) {
        super(context, name);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        List<Migration> migrations = getMigrations();
        // Only run migrations past the old version
        for (Migration migration : migrations) {
            if (oldVersion < migration.getVersion()) {
                migration.runMigration(db);
            }
        }
    }
    private List<Migration> getMigrations() {
        List<Migration> migrations = new ArrayList<>();
        migrations.add(new MigrationV2());
        migrations.add(new MigrationV3());
        // Sorting just to be safe, in case other people add migrations in the wrong order.
        Comparator<Migration> migrationComparator = new Comparator<Migration>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Migration m1, Migration m2) {
                return m1.getVersion().compareTo(m2.getVersion());
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(migrations, migrationComparator);
        return migrations;
    }
    private static class MigrationV2 implements Migration {
        @Override
        public Integer getVersion() {
            return 2;
        }
        @Override
        public void runMigration(Database db) {
            //Adding new table
            UserDao.createTable(db, false);
        }
    }
    private static class MigrationV3 implements Migration {
        @Override
        public Integer getVersion() {
            return 3;
        }
        @Override
        public void runMigration(Database db) {
            // Add new column to user table
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + UserDao.TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN " + UserDao.Properties.Age.columnName + " INTEGER");
        }
    }
    private interface Migration {
        Integer getVersion();
        void runMigration(Database db);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, What is are the classes MigrationV1,MigrationV2 ? What is the use of them?

Comment: Each time you increase database version, you implement new `Migration` class which contains, all required sql commands to alter tables from previous version to new version. So `MigrationV2` is migration from version 1 to version 2. `MigrationV3` is from 2 to 3, and so on.

Comment: All provided migration classes are checked in loop `for (Migration migration : migrations)`. It means, if previous version is 1, and new version is 3, then it will call both classes - `MigrationV2` and `MigrationV3`

Comment: If my version goes to 40 or 50. Do i need to write `Migration` class for 40 or 50 times?

Comment: You can write just one class `MigrationV50` which will have all required commands to transform tables from version 40 to 50